# How to call rest api from test class?

Tags: unit-test, rest-api

I have written a rest api class and working test class coverage. While calling the api class from the test class, i am facing the below error.

Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void execute() from the type httpPutApi at line 6 column 13

Test class:

```
       @isTest
       public class apiTest{
           public static testmethod void testCallout() {
           Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class,new apiHitEndPointURL());
           httpPutApi hpa = new httpPutApi(); 
           hpa.execute();
           }
       }
```

Mock data class:

```
           public class apiHitEndPointURL implements HttpCallOutMock{
               public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest req){
               String Json = '{ "dataMap": { "100007": "100008" , "100008": "100007"} }';
               HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
               res.setHeader('Content-Type','text/json');
               res.setBody(Json);    
               res.setStatusCode(200);
               return res;           
               }
           }
```

API Class:

```
     @RestResource(urlMapping = '/httpPutApi/*')
      global with sharing class httpPutApi {
      @HTTPPut
      global static List <wrapper> httpPutMethod(Map <String, String> dataMap) {
      ....
      }
      }
```

Could please some one help to call the api class in the test class with the correct signature?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your class `httpPutApi` doesn't contain the `execute` method, which you are trying to call. So this is an expected error

Comment: Indeed, why not directly call the "httpPutApi.httpPutMethod" method from the test?

Answer (score 1):

To test this method simply invoke the target method (httpPutMethod) with appropriate values and check the results:

```
@IsTest
public class ApiTest {       
    @IsTest
    static void testHttpPutApi() {
        List<wrapper> result = httpPutApi.httpPutMethod(new Map<String, String>{
                '100007' => '100008',
                '100008' => '100007'
            });
        // Now do your System.asserts with the results
    }
}
```